# Android Studio иконки цвета текста

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Создал через **File > New > Vector Asset** иконку, но она не меняет цвет, когда меняется цвет текста parent-а. Тут я понял, что я делаю что-то не то.

В `html` есть такая штука, как `icon font`, эти иконки как простые символы, меняют цвет вместе с остальным текстом.

Можно ли такое сделать в Android?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Оффтопом. Касательно `IconFont` есть данная [либа](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Косяк библиотеки, надо было дописать `.withIconTintingEnabled(true)`
Извините за свой ответ